# How do I install the open-source Radeon Vulkan driver?

Tags: amd-graphics

I'm interested in using the Vulkan backend. I have an RX 480 and the proprietary AMDGPU-PRO Vulkan backend worked on 16.04

After updating to 16.10, I installed the Padoka PPA and ran sudo apt-get dist-upgrade to update to the latest mesa. However, no games launch Vulkan correctly and vulkaninfo reports that it is an invalid command. So, I ran sudo apt-get install vulkan-utils and now vulkaninfo outputs [this](http://pastebin.com/6205Dfwt). What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Edit: manually installing mesa-vulkan-drivers with apt gives [this](http://pastebin.com/mW629jUy) output but it is equally useless.
Edit 2: Tried Antergos since it comes with the latest mesa out of the box, but that also did not have Vulkan support, even after installing vulkan-icd-loader and radeon-vulkan.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for open source yet did the proprietary drivers give you Vulkan on your AMD GPU ?  I am away from my AMD box until new year ... https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx

to install latest open source graphics drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/mesa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot now
```

as per https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa

then to verify

```
glxinfo
...
OpenGL Mesa 13.1.0-devel - padoka PPA
```

Comment: "UPDATE 2016-11-19
All packages have been purged, this PPA was meant for packaging testing only and it has served it's purpose." There's nothing in this PPA.

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Padoka PPA gives me the latest OpenGL drivers but does not give Vulkan support on my machine.

Comment: Did the AMD drivers render Vulcan ?

Comment: Yes, AMDGPU-PRO Vulkan worked back on 16.04